# user defined form validation in grails

Tags: validation, grails

I want to validate three form fields.
The usual method is like this:

```
class User {

  String name
  String password
  String personalInfo

  static constraints = {
    name(size: 4..20, unique:true, blank:false)
    password(size:8..20, blank:false)
    personalInfo(size: 1000, nullable:true)
  }
}
```

but in my gsp i'll be having all three textfields in the same name
eg:

```
<td>Name:</td><td><g:textfield name="property"/></td>
<td>Password:</td><td><g:textfield name="property"/></td>
<td>PersonalInfo:</td><td><g:textfield name="property"/></td>
```

How to validate this form????

Answer (score 2):

It is a really bad practice to give the same name to input fields in a form that are going to be mapped to different properties in the same domain class.
But if you cant, the fields will be sent as a list to your controller. So you can extract values in the controller like this:

`def parameterList = params.property as List`
`def name = parameterList[0]`
`def password = parameterList[1]`
`def personalInfo = parameterList[2]`

Then you can create your User object 
`def user = new User(name:name, personalInfo:personalInfo, password:password)`
`if (user.save()){ } else{ }`

As the best practice you must name your fields in the form differently

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
But is it possible to validate directly as a list without creating user object?

Comment: No, the constraints are defined in domain class (or in Command object), so you need to create it.

Comment: Suppose I want to validate my textboxes as a list without creating user object, how my domain class must look???

Comment: Probably you should ask yourself why you're trying to use grails in a way different from the one which is thought for.

Comment: @vasanth - again thats a bad idea. I'm not sure what exactly you want to achieve but command objects may be the solution you're looking for.